# Is there a benefit to parameterizing SQL WHERE clauses that always have the same value?

Tags: sql, sqlparameter

This question came up recently and I couldn't find any information on it. lets say I have an SQL query like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE type=1
```

The type that I'm selecting will never change. Are there any benefits, for performance or otherwise, to parameterizing this SQL (specifically adding the "1" as a parameter)?

My initial thought is that there wouldn't be, but someone I was talking to about this indicated that there probably would be, but didn't explain any further

Comment: Add a parameter to what? If you always have this WHERE clause then just create a view that has the WHERE clause as part of its definition